# SwiftUI, shortcutKey without button/View instance -- is it possible?

Tags: macos, swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts

in swiftUI exist `.keyboardShortcut()` modifier:

```
// run "doSomeAction()" on press of "b" key on the keyboard
Button("SomeBtn") { doSomeAction() }
    .keyboardShortcut("b", modifiers: [])
```

but for usage of this modifier you need to have an ***instance of button***.

Question is -- is there are possible to apply some modifier without creation of any useless Views?

What if I need to have 20 actions assigned to some keyboard keys?

Do I need to create 20 buttons and make it invisible even if this is really bad for performance?

Comment: A documentation says about *controls*, so yes you need buttons/menu to use `.keyboardShortcut`.

Comment: "Do I need to create 20 buttons and make it invisible even if this is really bad for performance?" As long as you don't re-render them needlessly, my guess is that the performance hit will be negligible.

Comment: @jnpdx I have loaded M1 cpu up to 90% just with window resize if have 20 buttons [and all of them is invisible] with `.keyboardShortcut` assigned . So no, this is bad for performance.

Comment: @Andrew I think there's a bit of a challenge in getting the buttons invisible, not affecting the layout, *and* responding to the key events, but in my test I mocked up, although I don't have the layout perfect, I can't recreate your issue of 90% CPU on an M1 when resizing. Maybe it would help to post your code for what you've tried, as it may be possible to adjust it to work.

Comment: added extra sample. With more simple structure. over 50% of m1 load on resize. https://prnt.sc/22x1od3

Comment: I have almost found better solution than usage of `.keyboardShortcut`. Better - because of few reasons: 1. Its works faster; 2. It does not need to create extra views; 3 it's works on ANY keyboard layout (`.keyboardShortcut` woks only in one keyboard layout); But I need to find the way to block "beep" sound on key press

Comment: @Andrew: I have an idea, you could put an observation method in some where in your app to observe if any key pressed, after getting that notification, you can do your work in your ViewModel or any where you want. But this idea has nothing to do with `.keyboardShortcut()`

Comment: @swiftPunk -- that's the my way. https://prnt.sc/22xezl1 Works much better than `.keyboardShortcut()`. But there is a problem right now - beep sound, like I have wrote in comment before this. So I didn't post the answer, just because of it's not completed yet :) Later I will post correct answer, when it will be ready

Comment: It must be working better because it is custom code.

Comment: @swiftPunk I have posted solution, if you interested in the code :)

Comment: @Andrew: I think you used deferent way than what I mentioned, I am not familiar the way you worked. My idea was working with notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Much better way than my another answer

Profits of this solution:

- Its works faster than `.keyboardShortcut()` way
- It does not need to create extra views/buttons;
- it's works on ANY keyboard layout ( `.keyboardShortcut()` works ONLY IN ONE keyboard layout);

Disadvantages:

- no hotkeys displayed in menus
- need to create custom hotkeys logic for different states of view (in some views need to use one hotkeys, in some subviews - another hotkeys)

Best way of usage:

```
someView()
    .keyboardReaction { myMainViewHotkeys($0) }

///////

func myMainViewHotkeys(_ event: NSEvent) -> NSEvent {
    switch event.keyCode {
    case KeyCode.escape:
        print("esc pressed!")
        return nil // disable beep sound
    case KeyCode.a:
        print("A pressed!")
        return nil // disable beep sound
    default:
        return event // beep sound will be here
    }
}
```

keyboardReactionModifier.swift

````
#if os(macOS)
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@available(macOS 11.0, *)
public extension View {
    
    /// * Reaction on keyboard's .keyDown will be executed only in case of view located at window where window.isKeyWindow == true
    /// * But reaction will be even if this window displays .sheet
    /// * KeyCode struct located in Essentials
    /// * Active Keyboard Layout does not matter
    /// ```
    ///.keyboardReaction { event in
    ///    switch event.keyCode {
    ///    case KeyCode.escape:
    ///        print("esc pressed!")
    ///        return nil // disable beep sound
    ///    case KeyCode.a:
    ///        print("A pressed!")
    ///        return nil // disable beep sound
    ///    default:
    ///        return event // beep sound will be here
    ///    }
    ///}
    /// ```
    func keyboardReaction(action: @escaping (NSEvent) -> (NSEvent?) ) -> some View {
        self.modifier(KeyboardReactiomModifier(action: action))
    }
}

@available(macOS 11.0, *)
private struct KeyboardReactiomModifier: ViewModifier {
    let action: (NSEvent) -> (NSEvent?)
    
    @State var window: NSWindow? = nil
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .wndAccessor { self.window = $0 }
            .onAppear {
                NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { event in
                    guard let window = window,
                          window.isKeyWindow
                    else { return event }
                    
                    return action(event)
                }
            }
    }
}
#endif
````

wndAccessorModifier.swift

````
#if os(macOS)
import SwiftUI
public extension View {
    /// With this modifier you're able to access to window from View.
    ///
    /// Usage:
    /// ```
    /// someView
    ///     .wndAccessor { wnd
    ///         self.window = wnd
    ///     }
    /// ```
    /// another sample:
    /// ```
    /// someView
    ///     .wndAccessor { wnd
    ///         wnd.title = "THIS... IS... WINDOOOOOW!"
    ///     }
    /// ```
    func wndAccessor(_ act: @escaping (NSWindow?) -> () )
        -> some View {
            self.modifier(WndTitleConfigurer(act: act))
    }
}

private struct WndTitleConfigurer: ViewModifier {
    let act: (NSWindow?) -> ()
    
    @State var window: NSWindow? = nil
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .getWindow($window)
            .onChange(of: window, perform: act )
    }
}

//////////////////////////////
///HELPERS
/////////////////////////////

private extension View {
    func getWindow(_ wnd: Binding<NSWindow?>) -> some View {
        self.background(WindowAccessor(window: wnd))
    }
}

private struct WindowAccessor: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var window: NSWindow?
    
    public func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window = view.window
        }
        return view
    }
    
    public func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}

#endif
````

KeyCode.swift

```
import SwiftUI

public struct KeyCode {
    public static let returnKey                 : UInt16 = 0x24
    public static let enter                     : UInt16 = 36 //0x4C
    public static let tab                       : UInt16 = 0x30
    public static let space                     : UInt16 = 0x31
    public static let delete                    : UInt16 = 0x33
    public static let escape                    : UInt16 = 0x35
    public static let command                   : UInt16 = 0x37
    public static let shift                     : UInt16 = 0x38
    public static let capsLock                  : UInt16 = 0x39
    public static let option                    : UInt16 = 0x3A
    public static let control                   : UInt16 = 0x3B
    public static let rightShift                : UInt16 = 0x3C
    public static let rightOption               : UInt16 = 0x3D
    public static let rightControl              : UInt16 = 0x3E
    public static let leftArrow                 : UInt16 = 0x7B
    public static let rightArrow                : UInt16 = 0x7C
    public static let downArrow                 : UInt16 = 0x7D
    public static let upArrow                   : UInt16 = 0x7E
    public static let volumeUp                  : UInt16 = 0x48
    public static let volumeDown                : UInt16 = 0x49
    public static let mute                      : UInt16 = 0x4A
    public static let help                      : UInt16 = 0x72
    public static let home                      : UInt16 = 0x73
    public static let pageUp                    : UInt16 = 0x74
    public static let forwardDelete             : UInt16 = 0x75
    public static let end                       : UInt16 = 0x77
    public static let pageDown                  : UInt16 = 0x79
    public static let function                  : UInt16 = 0x3F
    public static let f1                        : UInt16 = 0x7A
    public static let f2                        : UInt16 = 0x78
    public static let f4                        : UInt16 = 0x76
    public static let f5                        : UInt16 = 0x60
    public static let f6                        : UInt16 = 0x61
    public static let f7                        : UInt16 = 0x62
    public static let f3                        : UInt16 = 0x63
    public static let f8                        : UInt16 = 0x64
    public static let f9                        : UInt16 = 0x65
    public static let f10                       : UInt16 = 0x6D
    public static let f11                       : UInt16 = 0x67
    public static let f12                       : UInt16 = 0x6F
    public static let f13                       : UInt16 = 0x69
    public static let f14                       : UInt16 = 0x6B
    public static let f15                       : UInt16 = 0x71
    public static let f16                       : UInt16 = 0x6A
    public static let f17                       : UInt16 = 0x40
    public static let f18                       : UInt16 = 0x4F
    public static let f19                       : UInt16 = 0x50
    public static let f20                       : UInt16 = 0x5A
    
    // US-ANSI Keyboard Positions
    // eg. These key codes are for the physical key (in any keyboard layout)
    // at the location of the named key in the US-ANSI layout.
    public static let a                         : UInt16 = 0x00
    public static let b                         : UInt16 = 0x0B
    public static let c                         : UInt16 = 0x08
    public static let d                         : UInt16 = 0x02
    public static let e                         : UInt16 = 0x0E
    public static let f                         : UInt16 = 0x03
    public static let g                         : UInt16 = 0x05
    public static let h                         : UInt16 = 0x04
    public static let i                         : UInt16 = 0x22
    public static let j                         : UInt16 = 0x26
    public static let k                         : UInt16 = 0x28
    public static let l                         : UInt16 = 0x25
    public static let m                         : UInt16 = 0x2E
    public static let n                         : UInt16 = 0x2D
    public static let o                         : UInt16 = 0x1F
    public static let p                         : UInt16 = 0x23
    public static let q                         : UInt16 = 0x0C
    public static let r                         : UInt16 = 0x0F
    public static let s                         : UInt16 = 0x01
    public static let t                         : UInt16 = 0x11
    public static let u                         : UInt16 = 0x20
    public static let v                         : UInt16 = 0x09
    public static let w                         : UInt16 = 0x0D
    public static let x                         : UInt16 = 0x07
    public static let y                         : UInt16 = 0x10
    public static let z                         : UInt16 = 0x06
    
    public static let zero                      : UInt16 = 0x1D
    public static let one                       : UInt16 = 0x12
    public static let two                       : UInt16 = 0x13
    public static let three                     : UInt16 = 0x14
    public static let four                      : UInt16 = 0x15
    public static let five                      : UInt16 = 0x17
    public static let six                       : UInt16 = 0x16
    public static let seven                     : UInt16 = 0x1A
    public static let eight                     : UInt16 = 0x1C
    public static let nine                      : UInt16 = 0x19
    
    public static let equals                    : UInt16 = 0x18
    public static let minus                     : UInt16 = 0x1B
    public static let semicolon                 : UInt16 = 0x29
    public static let apostrophe                : UInt16 = 0x27
    public static let comma                     : UInt16 = 0x2B
    public static let period                    : UInt16 = 0x2F
    public static let forwardSlash              : UInt16 = 0x2C
    public static let backslash                 : UInt16 = 0x2A
    public static let grave                     : UInt16 = 0x32
    public static let leftBracket               : UInt16 = 0x21
    public static let rightBracket              : UInt16 = 0x1E
    
    public static let keypadDecimal             : UInt16 = 0x41
    public static let keypadMultiply            : UInt16 = 0x43
    public static let keypadPlus                : UInt16 = 0x45
    public static let keypadClear               : UInt16 = 0x47
    public static let keypadDivide              : UInt16 = 0x4B
    public static let keypadEnter               : UInt16 = 0x4C
    public static let keypadMinus               : UInt16 = 0x4E
    public static let keypadEquals              : UInt16 = 0x51
    public static let keypad0                   : UInt16 = 0x52
    public static let keypad1                   : UInt16 = 0x53
    public static let keypad2                   : UInt16 = 0x54
    public static let keypad3                   : UInt16 = 0x55
    public static let keypad4                   : UInt16 = 0x56
    public static let keypad5                   : UInt16 = 0x57
    public static let keypad6                   : UInt16 = 0x58
    public static let keypad7                   : UInt16 = 0x59
    public static let keypad8                   : UInt16 = 0x5B
    public static let keypad9                   : UInt16 = 0x5C
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how you do combinations with this approach?

Comment: @Wagm use `event.modificationFlags` or sth like this, check for contains needed key modifier

Answer (score 5):

> Please, look another answer. It is much better than this one.
> This one saved here just for history :)

---

Profits of this solution:

- Its works faster than `.keyboardShortcut()` way
- It does not need to create extra views/buttons;
- it's works on ANY keyboard layout ( `.keyboardShortcut()` works ONLY IN ONE keyboard layout);

Disadvantages:

- no hotkeys displayed in menus
- need to create custom hotkeys logic for different states of view (in some views need to use one hotkeys, in some subviews - another hotkeys)

---

Solution example:

```
struct WindowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: WindowModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("some text")
           .padding(60)
           // THIS IS FINAL SOLUTION
           .addCustomHotkeys(model.hotkeys)
           // THIS IS FINAL SOLUTION
    }
}
```

hotkeys initialisation inside ViewModel:

```
    // THIS IS FINAL SOLUTION
    let hotkeys: [HotkeyCombination] = [
        HotkeyCombination(keyBase: [], key: .kVK_ANSI_Q) { print("Q") },
        HotkeyCombination(keyBase: [.option], key: .kVK_ANSI_Q) { print("Option+Q") }
    ]
```

Files to use my solution:

HotKeys.swift :

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
extension View {
    func addCustomHotkeys( _ hotkeys: [HotkeyCombination] ) -> some View {
        self.modifier(HotKeysMod(hotkeys))
    }
}

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public struct HotKeysMod: ViewModifier {
    @State var subs = Set<AnyCancellable>() // Cancel onDisappear
    var hotkeys: [HotkeyCombination]
    
    init(_ hotkeys: [HotkeyCombination] ) {
        self.hotkeys = hotkeys
    }
    
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            DisableSoundsView(hotkeys:hotkeys)
            content
        }
    }
}

struct DisableSoundsView: NSViewRepresentable {
    var hotkeys: [HotkeyCombination]
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = DisableSoundsNSView()
        
        view.hotkeys = hotkeys
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) { }
}

class DisableSoundsNSView: NSView {
    var hotkeys: [HotkeyCombination] = []
    
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return hotkeysSubscription(combinations: hotkeys)
    }
}

fileprivate func hotkeysSubscription(combinations: [HotkeyCombination]) -> Bool {
    for comb in combinations {
        let basePressedCorrectly = comb.keyBasePressed
        
        if basePressedCorrectly && comb.key.isPressed {
            comb.action()
            return true
        }
    }
    
    return false
}

///////////////////////
///HELPERS
///////////////////////
struct HotkeyCombination {
    let keyBase: [KeyBase]
    let key: CGKeyCode
    let action: () -> ()
}

extension HotkeyCombination {
    var keyBasePressed: Bool {
        let mustBePressed    = KeyBase.allCases.filter{ keyBase.contains($0) }
        let mustBeNotPressed = KeyBase.allCases.filter{ !keyBase.contains($0) }
        
        for base in mustBePressed {
            if !base.isPressed {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        for base in mustBeNotPressed {
            if base.isPressed {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
}

enum KeyBase: CaseIterable {
    case option
    case command
    case shift
    case control
    
    var isPressed: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .option:
            return CGKeyCode.kVK_Option.isPressed  || CGKeyCode.kVK_RightOption.isPressed
        case .command:
            return CGKeyCode.kVK_Command.isPressed || CGKeyCode.kVK_RightCommand.isPressed
        case .shift:
            return CGKeyCode.kVK_Shift.isPressed   || CGKeyCode.kVK_RightShift.isPressed
        case .control:
            return CGKeyCode.kVK_Control.isPressed || CGKeyCode.kVK_RightControl.isPressed
        }
    }
}
```

CGKeyCode extension taken from:

https://gist.github.com/chipjarred/cbb324c797aec865918a8045c4b51d14

CGKeyCode.swift:

```
import Foundation

///https://gist.github.com/chipjarred/cbb324c797aec865918a8045c4b51d14
extension CGKeyCode {
    static let kVK_ANSI_A                    : CGKeyCode = 0x00
    static let kVK_ANSI_S                    : CGKeyCode = 0x01
    static let kVK_ANSI_D                    : CGKeyCode = 0x02
    static let kVK_ANSI_F                    : CGKeyCode = 0x03
    static let kVK_ANSI_H                    : CGKeyCode = 0x04
    static let kVK_ANSI_G                    : CGKeyCode = 0x05
    static let kVK_ANSI_Z                    : CGKeyCode = 0x06
    static let kVK_ANSI_X                    : CGKeyCode = 0x07
    static let kVK_ANSI_C                    : CGKeyCode = 0x08
    static let kVK_ANSI_V                    : CGKeyCode = 0x09
    static let kVK_ANSI_B                    : CGKeyCode = 0x0B
    static let kVK_ANSI_Q                    : CGKeyCode = 0x0C
    static let kVK_ANSI_W                    : CGKeyCode = 0x0D
    static let kVK_ANSI_E                    : CGKeyCode = 0x0E
    static let kVK_ANSI_R                    : CGKeyCode = 0x0F
    static let kVK_ANSI_Y                    : CGKeyCode = 0x10
    static let kVK_ANSI_T                    : CGKeyCode = 0x11
    static let kVK_ANSI_1                    : CGKeyCode = 0x12
    static let kVK_ANSI_2                    : CGKeyCode = 0x13
    static let kVK_ANSI_3                    : CGKeyCode = 0x14
    static let kVK_ANSI_4                    : CGKeyCode = 0x15
    static let kVK_ANSI_6                    : CGKeyCode = 0x16
    static let kVK_ANSI_5                    : CGKeyCode = 0x17
    static let kVK_ANSI_Equal                : CGKeyCode = 0x18
    static let kVK_ANSI_9                    : CGKeyCode = 0x19
    static let kVK_ANSI_7                    : CGKeyCode = 0x1A
    static let kVK_ANSI_Minus                : CGKeyCode = 0x1B
    static let kVK_ANSI_8                    : CGKeyCode = 0x1C
    static let kVK_ANSI_0                    : CGKeyCode = 0x1D
    static let kVK_ANSI_RightBracket         : CGKeyCode = 0x1E
    static let kVK_ANSI_O                    : CGKeyCode = 0x1F
    static let kVK_ANSI_U                    : CGKeyCode = 0x20
    static let kVK_ANSI_LeftBracket          : CGKeyCode = 0x21
    static let kVK_ANSI_I                    : CGKeyCode = 0x22
    static let kVK_ANSI_P                    : CGKeyCode = 0x23
    static let kVK_ANSI_L                    : CGKeyCode = 0x25
    static let kVK_ANSI_J                    : CGKeyCode = 0x26
    static let kVK_ANSI_Quote                : CGKeyCode = 0x27
    static let kVK_ANSI_K                    : CGKeyCode = 0x28
    static let kVK_ANSI_Semicolon            : CGKeyCode = 0x29
    static let kVK_ANSI_Backslash            : CGKeyCode = 0x2A
    static let kVK_ANSI_Comma                : CGKeyCode = 0x2B
    static let kVK_ANSI_Slash                : CGKeyCode = 0x2C
    static let kVK_ANSI_N                    : CGKeyCode = 0x2D
    static let kVK_ANSI_M                    : CGKeyCode = 0x2E
    static let kVK_ANSI_Period               : CGKeyCode = 0x2F
    static let kVK_ANSI_Grave                : CGKeyCode = 0x32
    static let kVK_ANSI_KeypadDecimal        : CGKeyCode = 0x41
    static let kVK_ANSI_KeypadMultiply       : CGKeyCode = 0x43
    static let kVK_ANSI_KeypadPlus           : CGKeyCode = 0x45
    static let kVK_ANSI_KeypadClear          : CGKeyCode = 0x47
    static let kVK_ANSI_KeypadDivide         : CGKeyCode = 0x4B
    static let kVK_ANSI_KeypadEnter          : CGKeyCode = 0x4C
    static let kVK_ANSI_KeypadMinus          : CGKeyCode = 0x4E
    static let kVK_ANSI_KeypadEquals         : CGKeyCode = 0x51
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad0              : CGKeyCode = 0x52
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad1              : CGKeyCode = 0x53
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad2              : CGKeyCode = 0x54
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad3              : CGKeyCode = 0x55
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad4              : CGKeyCode = 0x56
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad5              : CGKeyCode = 0x57
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad6              : CGKeyCode = 0x58
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad7              : CGKeyCode = 0x59
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad8              : CGKeyCode = 0x5B
    static let kVK_ANSI_Keypad9              : CGKeyCode = 0x5C

    // keycodes for keys that are independent of keyboard layout
    static let kVK_Return                    : CGKeyCode = 0x24
    static let kVK_Tab                       : CGKeyCode = 0x30
    static let kVK_Space                     : CGKeyCode = 0x31
    static let kVK_Delete                    : CGKeyCode = 0x33
    static let kVK_Escape                    : CGKeyCode = 0x35
    static let kVK_Command                   : CGKeyCode = 0x37
    static let kVK_Shift                     : CGKeyCode = 0x38
    static let kVK_CapsLock                  : CGKeyCode = 0x39
    static let kVK_Option                    : CGKeyCode = 0x3A
    static let kVK_Control                   : CGKeyCode = 0x3B
    static let kVK_RightCommand              : CGKeyCode = 0x36 // Out of order
    static let kVK_RightShift                : CGKeyCode = 0x3C
    static let kVK_RightOption               : CGKeyCode = 0x3D
    static let kVK_RightControl              : CGKeyCode = 0x3E
    static let kVK_Function                  : CGKeyCode = 0x3F
    static let kVK_F17                       : CGKeyCode = 0x40
    static let kVK_VolumeUp                  : CGKeyCode = 0x48
    static let kVK_VolumeDown                : CGKeyCode = 0x49
    static let kVK_Mute                      : CGKeyCode = 0x4A
    static let kVK_F18                       : CGKeyCode = 0x4F
    static let kVK_F19                       : CGKeyCode = 0x50
    static let kVK_F20                       : CGKeyCode = 0x5A
    static let kVK_F5                        : CGKeyCode = 0x60
    static let kVK_F6                        : CGKeyCode = 0x61
    static let kVK_F7                        : CGKeyCode = 0x62
    static let kVK_F3                        : CGKeyCode = 0x63
    static let kVK_F8                        : CGKeyCode = 0x64
    static let kVK_F9                        : CGKeyCode = 0x65
    static let kVK_F11                       : CGKeyCode = 0x67
    static let kVK_F13                       : CGKeyCode = 0x69
    static let kVK_F16                       : CGKeyCode = 0x6A
    static let kVK_F14                       : CGKeyCode = 0x6B
    static let kVK_F10                       : CGKeyCode = 0x6D
    static let kVK_F12                       : CGKeyCode = 0x6F
    static let kVK_F15                       : CGKeyCode = 0x71
    static let kVK_Help                      : CGKeyCode = 0x72
    static let kVK_Home                      : CGKeyCode = 0x73
    static let kVK_PageUp                    : CGKeyCode = 0x74
    static let kVK_ForwardDelete             : CGKeyCode = 0x75
    static let kVK_F4                        : CGKeyCode = 0x76
    static let kVK_End                       : CGKeyCode = 0x77
    static let kVK_F2                        : CGKeyCode = 0x78
    static let kVK_PageDown                  : CGKeyCode = 0x79
    static let kVK_F1                        : CGKeyCode = 0x7A
    static let kVK_LeftArrow                 : CGKeyCode = 0x7B
    static let kVK_RightArrow                : CGKeyCode = 0x7C
    static let kVK_DownArrow                 : CGKeyCode = 0x7D
    static let kVK_UpArrow                   : CGKeyCode = 0x7E

    // ISO keyboards only
    static let kVK_ISO_Section               : CGKeyCode = 0x0A

    // JIS keyboards only
    static let kVK_JIS_Yen                   : CGKeyCode = 0x5D
    static let kVK_JIS_Underscore            : CGKeyCode = 0x5E
    static let kVK_JIS_KeypadComma           : CGKeyCode = 0x5F
    static let kVK_JIS_Eisu                  : CGKeyCode = 0x66
    static let kVK_JIS_Kana                  : CGKeyCode = 0x68

    var isModifier: Bool {
        return (.kVK_RightCommand...(.kVK_Function)).contains(self)
    }

    var baseModifier: CGKeyCode?
    {
        if (.kVK_Command...(.kVK_Control)).contains(self)
                || self == .kVK_Function
        {
                return self
        }

        switch self
        {
                case .kVK_RightShift: return .kVK_Shift
                case .kVK_RightCommand: return .kVK_Command
                case .kVK_RightOption: return .kVK_Option
                case .kVK_RightControl: return .kVK_Control

                default: return nil
        }
    }
    
    var isPressed: Bool {
        CGEventSource.keyState(.combinedSessionState, key: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Best solution around.

Comment: I wish that some solution could be better, but didn't found better than this =(

Comment: @HelloTimo I have post anoter answer. It's much better than my old one